# Printing JTextArea Form Feed Characters as Page Breaks

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtextarea

I am trying to print a JTextArea using the Java Print Service API:

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(path)));
        JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
        PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        PrintService defaultService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

        text.read(br, null);
        text.print(null, null, true, defaultService, pras, true);
```

The JTextArea is loaded up from a file that contains form feed characters (\f). How can I get these characters to act as a page break on my local printer?

Answer (score 4):

```
public class PagedTextArea extends JTextArea implements Printable, Pageable {
    JTextArea singlePageTextArea;

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex)
                throws PrinterException {
        if (singlePageTextArea == null) {

            // Copy attributes to the singlePageTextArea:
            singlePageTextArea = new JTextArea();
            singlePageTextArea.setBounds(getBounds());
        }

        String[] pages = getText().split("\f");
        if (pageIndex >= pages.length) {
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }
        singlePageTextArea.setText(pages[pageIndex]);
        singlePageTextArea.printAll(graphics);
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }


    @Override
    public int getNumberOfPages() {
        String[] pages = getText().split("\f");
        return pages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public PageFormat getPageFormat(int pageIndex) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        return new PageFormat();
    }

    @Override
    public Printable getPrintable(int pageIndex) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        return this;
    }
}
```

And to print:

```
            PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            job.setPrintable(pagedTextArea);
            PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

            boolean ok = job.printDialog(pras);
            if (ok) {
                System.out.println("Printing...");
                try {
                    job.print();
                } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                    System.out.println("The job did not successfully complete");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Could not print");
            }
```

You probably want to use the PageFormat to do a Graphics2D.translate to x, y of the page.

Comment: I have implemented this class and made several attempts to get it to work without any success. Perhaps you could be a little more verbose in your answer?

Comment: I forgot the Pageable interface; it is a bit convoluted now. Extended the code.

Comment: Still trying to sort this all out. I believe I am getting very close as I get 3 empty pages printed where i expect 3 pages. Thanks for getting me this far Joop!

Comment: Maybe a translate and scale to pdfFormat.getImageableX/Y/Width/Height.

Comment: So far the only way I can get anything to print properly on the pages is to use graphics.printString(). This is not optimal since it is fairly resource intensive and requires page height calculations since some sections between form feed characters could be multiple pages. This pretty much removes all the benefits and simplicity of JTextArea.print().

Answer (score 1):

The original page breaks are probably based on line the count for a fixed-pitch printer. `JTextArea` uses a completely different way of measuring text based on `FontMetrics`, which varies from one OS to another. I'd ignore the line feeds and let `JTextArea` do its thing with [`print()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#print%28%29).

Edit: If *each invoice will be a different length*, maybe you can separate them into individual text areas and `append()` each `Printable` to a [`Book`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/print/Book.html). You can have an inner class that `implements Printable`, or you might be able to use the text area's `getPrintable()` method.

Comment: The original page breaks (form feed characters) are generated based on logical breaks in data/reports. Think of printing itemized invoices for multiple clients. Each invoice will be a different length. The raw text is generated with \f characters to delimit the client reports.

Comment: Is there any way to get go back to the report's source?

Comment: The report is a plain text file with form feed characters. I have access to that text file on the local file system. I also have access the report generator but I do not want to change its raw text output.

Comment: I will look into the creating printables and appening them into a book.